# Regex pattern for lowercase letters, optional digits, and constrained length

Tags: php, javascript, regex

What are the JavaScript and PHP regex patterns if a string is to fulfill the following conditions:

1. The string should be between (and including) 4 and 20 characters
2. It can contain only lowercase alphabets and, optionally, digits.
3. It MUST contain at least 1 alphabet

The following strings formats are acceptable :

- `randy`
- `randy39`
- `39randy`
- `r789456123`

The following are NOT acceptable:

- `ran`
- `3546`
- `r_andy`
- `__3912`

Comment: Have you tried something to solve your task or you just came to SO for community to do your work?

Comment: I've tried /^([a-z0-9]){3,5}$/

Comment: Try /^([a-z0-9]{4,20})$/ if you need the capturing brackets, or /^[a-z0-9]{4,20}$/ if you don't, but that doesn't test for at least 1 alpha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [lookahead assertion](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to verify that the string contains a letter somewhere.

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{4,20}$/
```

This should work in both JavaScript and PHP alike.

Answer (score 0):

Use two regexes: `/^[a-z0-9]{4,20}$/` and `/[a-z]/` (the actual syntax might differ between PHP and Javascript)